# Angular Как открыть следующее изображение в массиве / Open next image

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller

Контроллер:

```
$http.get('/device/record/' + rid);
.then(function success(response) {
    $scope.link = [];
    response.data.forEach(function (element, index) {
    $scope.link.push({"filename": "/public/image/"+ 
    response.data[index].filename});
    });
    console.log($scope.link);
  });
```

Возвращает ссылки на изображения:

```
/public/image/lastfoto1.jpg
/public/image/newimage.jpg
```

На странице отображаю эти картинки:

```
<div ng-repeat="(i, slide) in link">
<img ng-click="" ng-src="{{ slide.filename }}" alt="foto" height="250" width="250"/>
</div>
```

Как сделать, чтобы отображалось первое изображения и по клику на нём менялось на следующее?

Comment: Применить компоненту слайдер. Либо сделать обработчик события нажатия на ``<img>``и менять ``ng-src``

Comment: Слайдер бы не хотелось, ng-click предпочтительнее. Но уже голову сломал в его реализации, а толку нет.

Comment: Направьте в правильном направлен с ng-click и функцией обработчиком

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так, как вариант:

```
<img ng-click="changeImage()" ng-src="{{ current.filename }}" alt="foto" height="250" width="250"/>
```

В контроллере:

```
$http.get('/device/record/' + rid);
   .then(function success(response) {
        $scope.link = [];
        response.data.forEach(function (element, index) {
        $scope.link.push({"filename": "/public/image/"+ 
        response.data[index].filename});
        $scope.current = $scope.link[0];
        $scope.currentIdx = 0;
   });       
});

$scope.changeImage = function() {
    if($scope.currentIdx < $scope.link.length) {
        $scope.currentIdx++;
    } else {
        $scope.currentIdx = 0;
    }
    $scope.current = $scope.link[$scope.currentIdx];
}
```

Comment: Странно. Ошибки никакой нет, но и по клику изображение не меняется!

Comment: По моим наблюдениям, функция 'changeImage', всегда возвращает $scope.currentIdx = 0, а это первое изображение. Потому оно и не меняется. Значит, условие '$scope.currentIdx < $scope.link.lenght', всегда возвращает false. Как считаете, чем это может быть вызвано?

Comment: Почему-то $scope.link.lenght равно undefined. Условие не отрабатывает.

Comment: Разобрался. Ошибка в написании $scope.link.lenght -> $scope.link.length. Спасибо Вам!